# OWIN Challenge() method not executed when using multiple ADFS + Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, adfs, katana

My ASP.Net app uses OWIN/Katana/Claims, and allows login using:

1. Traditional username/password (exists for all users)
2. Google
3. Azure AD

It works perfectly, and all the necessary redirects/claims transfers work well (the user NameIdentifier/Provider(/tenant) details are passed back to my app so the unique id values can be linked up).  Note that users do not sign up/register for the app - access is provisioned by their organisation's super-user, and a username/password sent to them which they can then hook up with Google/Azure.

However, I now need to extend this functionality to allow users to hook up to their organisation's ADFS provider.  The only working example for this that's remotely close is here ([tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1166/aspnet-mvc-multiple-adfs-owin-katana)/[code](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/multiple-adfs-owin-katana)), but it is strictly based on ADFS-only.  When I adapt this into my project, it doesn't work.

My entire StartupAuth file is shown below.  I appreciate that there may be configuration errors, but based on the scraps of samples I've found over the last six weeks, this is the best I've had.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // STANDARD CODE FOR APP COOKIE AND GOOGLE - WORKS PERFECTLY

        CookieAuthenticationOptions coa = new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieName = "MyAppName",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login.aspx"),
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { OnValidateIdentity = context =>
            {
                dynamic ret = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // Verify that "userId" and "customerId" claims exist, and that each has a valid value (greater than zero) - removed for brevity
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                });
                return ret;
            } }
        };
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(coa.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(coa);

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions {
            ClientId = "84***********************k3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "jue*****************Ppi"
        });



        // NEW CODE THAT FAILS TO WORK - SPECIFYING EACH CUSTOMER'S ADFS AS A NEW WSFED AUTH OPTION


        WsFederation.WsFederationAuthenticationOptions Adfs_CompanyA = new WsFederation.WsFederationAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            MetadataAddress = "https://CompanyA.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
            AuthenticationType = AdfsAuthenticationTypes.CompanyA,
            Wtrealm = "https://www.CompanyA.co.uk/MyAppName"
        };

        WsFederation.WsFederationAuthenticationOptions Adfs_CompanyB = new WsFederation.WsFederationAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            MetadataAddress = "https://CompanyB.net/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
            AuthenticationType = AdfsAuthenticationTypes.CompanyB,
            Wtrealm = "http://www.CompanyB.co.uk/azure/MyAppName"
        };

        // User (who is logged in), route for hyperlink "Link my account with ADFS"
        app.Map("/SSO/LinkUserAccount/ADFS/process", configuration => { configuration.UseWsFederationAuthentication(Adfs_CompanyA); });

        // CompanyA ADFS - single sign-on route
        app.Map("/SSO/Login/CompanyA/ADFS/Go", configuration => { configuration.UseWsFederationAuthentication(Adfs_CompanyA); });

        // CompanyB ADFS - single sign-on route
        app.Map("/SSO/Login/CompanyB/ADFS/Go", configuration => { configuration.UseWsFederationAuthentication(Adfs_CompanyB); });
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use to issue an OWIN Challenge:

```
string provider = MyApp.SingleSignOn.GetCustomerAdfsAuthenticationType(customerName);
string redirectUrl = string.Format("{0}/SSO/Login/{1}/ADFS/Go", Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), provider); // creates https://myapp.com/SSO/Login/CompanyA/ADFS/Go for CompanyA users
Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, provider);
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End();
```

This is webforms, but please don't let that stop MVC pro's from contributing.  The code is virtually identical anyway and I'm using routes.

The problem I have is that when the user clicks on the "sign-on with ADFS" link, e.g. URL becomes https://myapp.com/SSO/Login/CompanyA/ADFS
I get an 401 Unauthorized error, instead of the user being redirected to the ADFS login page.
In web.config, I allow unauthorized access to path "SSO".  For some reason the `Challenge()` method never redirects the user, it simply gets ignored and the code reaches the point where it returns a 401.  The value of string `provider` exactly matches the `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType` value defined in Startup.Auth.

I've been sturggling with this now for six weeks, so this is getting a bounty at the first opportunity, and a crate of beer delivered to your chosen address when it is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.  Amazingly, it was as simple as me missing this from the end of StartupAuth:

```
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up OWIN logging? Any clues there?

Also [Test driving the WS-Federation Authentication Middleware for Katana](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/02/21/test-driving-the-ws-federation-authentication-middleware-for-katana/).

Have a look at the code in [IdentityServer 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer). There's a WS-Fed plugin there and the documentation is  [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) (at the bottom).

Comment: The sample code appears to set up a single ADFS instance, which is something I've come across in the many other projects online.  I can't see any use of ADFS in tandem with other providers though.  I'll take a look at logging today, although its not something I've done before.

Comment: IdentityServer 3 supports social (Google etc,,) OpenID Connect, OAuth2 and WS-Fed